# jQuery toggle passed boolean false first has different transition

Tags: boolean, toggle, jquery-mobile, jquery

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/FzZwt/8/

If I pass false to the toggle() first the transition is set to slow
If I pass true to the toggle() first the transition is not set

Can I pass a transition with a boolean in the toggle()?

Example:

```
var show = true;
$('#elem').toggle(show, 'slow');
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
<div>Boolean Test 1 - Passing TRUE first</div>
<input type="radio" name="boolean" id="true" value="true" />
<label for="true">Yes</label>                
<input type="radio" name="boolean" id="false" value="false" checked="checked"/>
<label for="false">No</label>
<div class="hidden" name="hidden_div" id="hidden_div">Show Me!!!</div>
</fieldset>
</div>

<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
<div>Boolean Test 2 - Passing FALSE First</div>
<input type="radio" name="boolean2" id="true" value="true" />
<label for="true">Yes</label>                
<input type="radio" name="boolean2" id="false" value="false" checked="checked"/>
<label for="false">No</label>
<div class="hidden" name="hidden_div2" id="hidden_div2">Show Me!!!</div>
</fieldset>
</div>

</div>
```

JS

```
$(".hidden").hide();

$("[name=boolean]").change(function() {
    var show = $('input[name=boolean]:checked').val() == "true";
    alert('Passing first: '+show);
    $("#hidden_div").toggle(show);
});

$("[name=boolean2]").change(function() {
    var show = $(this).val();
    alert('Passing First: '+show);
    $("#hidden_div2").toggle(show);
});
```

Comment: `var show = $(this).val();` This is a string, not a boolean. Cast it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing string values when it expects either a boolean or an animation speed (either a number or one of the values that translates to numbers).

If you want to pass booleans, you'll need to cast them as Tomalak mentions

I made a couple of changes; is this what you're looking for?

```
$(".hidden").hide();

$("[name=boolean]").change(function() {
    var show = ($('input[name=boolean]:checked').val() == 'true') ? true : false;
    $("#hidden_div").toggle(show );
});

$("[name=boolean2]").change(function() {
    var show = ($(this).val() == "true") ? true : false ;
    $("#hidden_div2").toggle(show );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FzZwt/11/

Answer (score 0):

According to the [API](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display), the form of `toggle()` where a boolean determines whether to show or hide doesn't take any other parameters. So unfortunately, I think we have to do something like:

```
if (myBoolean) {
    $myElement.show(MY_DURATION_CONSTANT, myEasing);
} else {
    $myElement.hide(MY_DURATION_CONSTANT, myEasing);
}
```

Not very elegant, but I think this is necessary because of the way the `toggle` function is overloaded.